# Use Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=\{2-\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence that satisfies $x_1 > 1$.  Using MCT, prove that $\{x_n\}_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Comment: The notation is weird, but if $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ is increasing then if it's bounded above then the sequence converge by MCT.

Comment: @upvoters Please explain why you upvote such a naked PSQ by a repeating offender.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is strictly decreasing and bounded  below by $1$. In fact, $x_1>1$ and if $x_n>1$ then 
$$x_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{x_n}>2-1=1.$$
Moreover 
$$x_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{x_n}<x_n\Leftrightarrow \frac{(x_n-1)^2}{x_n}>0$$
and the the last inequality holds.
Hence, by MCT, the sequence $(x_n)_n$ has a finite limit $L\geq 1$.

Moreover, by taking the limit in the equation $x_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{x_n}$ we obtain
$L=2-\frac{1}{L}$ which implies that $L=1$.

Comment: How do you show that it is decreasing?